# Not able to scrub sensitive data on sentry

Tags: next.js, sentry

I want to scrub password field coming anywhere from the xhr requests but it is not getting scrubbed on sentry platform.

I have integrated sentry to one of my NextJS application and I have also disabled default data scrubbing both globally (from all projects) and specifically for that project as well which sentry provides by default. I have used advanced data scrubbing for the same under Settings > Security & Privacy globally. I'm also doing the same for the token field using the same steps and it is working fine but it is not working for the password field using the same steps as well.

It looks to me that it is treating password as a string and not an object field. Not sure if that's the case also since I'm sending it in the body to the api, so should get logged as an  object field on the sentry. Also, please let me know what can be done in this case also

Please find below the screenshots for the same

[image]

[image]

[image]